# Counting the string phrase in String Grid

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, data-structures

You are given an n*m grid which contains lower case English letters. How many times does the phrase "saba" appear horizontally, vertically, and diagonally in the grid?

Counting horizontally, vertically and diagonally.

```
#include<iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int TotalCount(vector<string> Str, int ItemCount)
{
string Text = "saba";
string VerticalString = "";
string DiagonalOneString = "";
string DiagonalTwoString = "";
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ItemCount; ++i)
{
    string& currentRow = Str[i];
    VerticalString = VerticalString.append(&currentRow.at(0));
    DiagonalOneString = DiagonalOneString.append(&currentRow.at(i));
    DiagonalTwoString = 
    DiagonalTwoString.append(&currentRow.at(currentRow.length() - 1 - i));

    if ((currentRow.find(Text) != string::npos) || (VerticalString.find(Text) != string::npos) || (DiagonalOneString.find(Text) != string::npos) || (DiagonalTwoString.find(Text) != string::npos))
    {
        count++;
    }
}
return count;
}

int main()
{
int total = 0;
int row;
cin >> row;
vector<string> rows;
// read each row and append to the "rows" vector
for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
{
    string line;
    cin >> line;
    rows.push_back(line);
}
cout << TotalCount(rows, row);
return 0;
}
```

Input format

First line: Two integer n and m, where n denotes (1 <= n,m <= 100) the number of rows and m denotes the number of columns in the grid
Next n lines: Each line must contain a string of length m which contains lower-case English letters only

```
Sample Input
5 5
safer
amjad
babol
aaron
songs

Expected Output
2
```

It seems like VerticalString copies the whole string instead of copying the character at the specified position. I am not getting the expected count. Can please someone let me know why the count is coming wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you do know that the number of elements in a vector is in the vector itself? And that it can be gotten with e.g. `Str.size()`? That means you don't need to pass along the size of the vector as an argument to your function calls.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I completely forgot about that. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your vertical string is `saba`, `count` will increment.  But `count` will increment again when your vertical string is `sabas`, for the same hit.

Also, you probably meant to search diagonals besides just the two between corners.  Looking at only 2 diagonals allows for the possibility of overlooking valid hits.  And reading both directions is probably required.

My recommendation would be to break down the problem into counting hits from each horizontal row, counting hits from each vertical row (could transpose the matrix and re-use the first function), counting diagonals (northeast to southwest), and finally counting diagonals (northwest to southeast).  I.e., dedicate a new function for each of them, and sum the results.

Printing strings you're testing would greatly help you with debugging, too.